# Add html code to BACKEND template manager of protostar

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I am trying to make protostar template BACKEND more user friendly. I want to add a left sidebar with options such as "Fonts", "Layout", "..." etc. I also would like to be able to style the backend options, fieldsets and fields.

Please note: This question is for the Joomla administrator backend and not for the front end site.

I know html and css well but I dont know where to override the backend template manager looks like some of the theme providers do. For example:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You could try to see how other template frameworks does this. Most frameworks like [Gantry](http://www.gantry-framework.org/) and [T3 Framework](http://www.t3-framework.org/) have customized backend layouts.

Comment: Did you try if it works just like the front end? I.e. is there a administrator/templates/<yourtemplatename>/html folder? If yes, try creating the same structure as you would in the front end, copy the view file you want to manipulate and have fun ;-)